# How to add background image with zoom in/out to sigma.js

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I am using sigma.js and try to add background image instead of background color. It work find but not possible to zoom in/out. Someone already add a question [here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/127) but no answer yet. So anyone have a solution of this issue?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: Hello. Yes I found it. Please check the commit below.
https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/pull/698/commits/1b557ef3ea5df286f919edec749e8ee270e27de1

Answer (score 1):

After a simple lucky search i found the following solution:

```
var c = s.camera;
// Zoom out - single frame :
c.goTo({
   ratio: c.ratio * c.settings('zoomingRatio')
});

// Zoom in - single frame :
c.goTo({
   ratio: c.ratio / c.settings('zoomingRatio')
});

// Zoom out - animation :
sigma.misc.animation.camera(c, {
   ratio: c.ratio * c.settings('zoomingRatio')
}, {
   duration: 200
});

// Zoom in - animation :
sigma.misc.animation.camera(c, {
   ratio: c.ratio / c.settings('zoomingRatio')
}, {
   duration: 200
});
```